# UWP C++ Drag and Drop CanDrop does not exist

Tags: c++, drag-and-drop, uwp

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/app-to-app/drag-and-drop) to implement Drag and Drop for my C++ UWP Project.
I can set AllowDrop to my StackPanel, but CanDrag simply does not exist. I want to drag Frames, so i thought that only Frames are not Dragable, but even Images do not have a property CanDrag or IsDragEnabled or anything like that.

How can i add the Drag functionality to my Frame elements??

Comment: Image,Frame and StackPanel  controls do have `CanDrag` properties. My environment is OS build 15063.  Could you please share your environment?

Comment: Do you mean my Windows 10 version? It is Version 10.0.15063 Build 15063
Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3
But my App is not for windows 10 it is for Windows 8.1